# Tire Equivalent of an Elasticsearch JSON Query

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have a query in standard JSON format that works pretty fine when queried directly from command line. The json is:

```
{"fields" : ["id"],
 "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[
        {
          "custom_score" : {
              "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                  "should" : [
                    {
                      "term" : {"a.in.group" : "abcd"}
                    },
                    {
                      "term" : {"a.in.group": "ALL"}
                    }
                   ]
                 }
              },
            "boost" : 1.0,
            "script" : "_score"
            }
        },

        {
          "custom_score" : {
              "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                  "should" : [
                    {
                      "term" : {"b.in.prefix" : pre}
                    },
                    {
                      "term" : {"b.in.group" : "abc"}
                    }
                   ]
                 }
              },
            "boost" : 1.0,
            "script" : "_score"
            }
        }
       ]
      }
    }
}
```

This is giving me result as desired:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/test/rule/_search" -d @query.json
{"took":6,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":2.3251607,"hits":[{"_index":"memphis","_type":"rule","_id":"1","_score":2.3251607,"fields":{"id":1}}]}}
```

But I am unable to find the right syntex for the equivalent tire query. I tried:

```
s=Tire.search('test/rule') do
    query do
        boolean do
            must [
                query do
                    boolean do
                        should { string "a.in.group:abcd" }
                        should { string "a.in.group:ALL" }
                    end
                end
                query do
                    boolean do
                        should { string "b.in.prefix:pre" }
                        should { string "b.in.group:abc" }
                    end
                end
            ]
        end
    end

    fields :id
end
```

But this is giving me syntax error:

```
ruby -c query.rb 
query.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting ']'
query.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting keyword_end
query.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

I couldn't find any help on any other forum. Problem occurs when I try to put multiple queries in the must block. Please help.

Thanks in Advance

-Azitabh

Comment: I don't think `must` takes an array as a parameter. Try `must do...end`.

Comment: Hi Robin,
I tried the must do...end block as suggested. The syntax error is gone but it is giving me error while executing. This is the error:

bundle exec ruby query.rb 
[REQUEST FAILED] NoMethodError undefined method `query' for #<Tire::Search::Query:0x00000001e12ac0 @value={}>
The I removed the query d0...end thing from inside must. Now the structure is:
 
query do

boolean do

must do

boolean do

should

should

end

boolean do

should

should

end

end

end

end

This is syntactically correct and runs OK as well but is not generating the query I want. Contd...

Comment: This is basically collapsing all the boolean statements inside must as one and generates this:
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/test/rule/_search?pretty=true" -d'{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"should":[{"query_string":{"query":"a.in.group:abcd"}},{"query_string":{"query":"a.in.group:ALL"}},{"query_string":{"query":"b.in.prefix:pre"}},{"query_string":{"query":"b.in.group:abc"}}]}}]}},"fields":["id"]}'
This will give me results matching any of the four should statements. But I want my results to match one of the 1st two shoulds and one of the last two. This is what my actual query is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this will do the trick:

```
s = Tire.search 'test/rule' do
    query do
      boolean do
          must do
              custom_score :boost => 1.0, :script => "_score" do
                boolean do
                    should { term 'a.in.group', "abcd" }
                    should { term 'a.in.group', "ALL" }
                end
              end
          end
          must do
              custom_score :boost => 1.0, :script => "_score" do
                boolean do
                    should { term 'b.in.prefix', pre }
                    should { term 'b.in.group', "abc" }
                end
              end
          end
      end
    end
    fields :id
end
```